# PLSQL Collections - to create a collection of records or not?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am new to Oracle PL/SQL and am having some difficulty conceptualizing collections with regard to records.

I have the following problem: 
I want to compare various fields of a record from the client table to various fields of a record from the person table. e.g., LName, FName, Soc. (unfortunately, there is no identifier to easily link the two).

For the client table, I plan on creating a cursor and fetching it into a record (and looping), since **for each record of the client table, I want to look through all of the person records and see if there is a best match**. If there are 100 clients, there should not be more than 100 matches.

This is where I am not sure if I should:

- A) Use a collection of records for
  the person table, or
- B) Use a
  collection for LName, a collection
  for FName, a collection for Soc.

If I use A, how do I reference a specific column within the record? This is how I was proceeding with the code, but I am getting a little lost.

If I use B, is there a way to ensure that I am comparing columns with the same record? i.e., If I compare the client record for John Doe 111-222-3333 I want to make sure that if I get a match that it is from a single record, and not record 10 FName = John, record 200 LNAME = Doe, record 5000 Soc = 111-222-3333.

Answers with Oracle PL/SQL syntax are greatly appreciated, as I am still learning and will be too easily confused by other languages... Below are the beginnings of my code...

Thank you!

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR client_cur IS
  SELECT id_client, nm_client_last, nm_client_first, nbr_client_ssn,
         cd_client_gender, dt_client_birth
    FROM client
   WHERE yr_service_fiscal BETWEEN 2007 AND 2009
ORDER BY nm_client_last,
         nm_client_first,
         nbr_client_ssn,
         cd_client_gender,
         dt_client_birth;

  CURSOR person_cur IS
  SELECT id_person, nm_person_last, nm_person_first, nbr_person_id_number,
         cd_person_sex, dt_person_birth
    FROM person
   WHERE EXTRACT (YEAR FROM dt_last_update) >= 2007
     AND nm_person_full != 'Employee,Conversion'
ORDER BY nm_person_last,
         nm_person_first,
         nbr_person_id_number,
         cd_person_sex,
         dt_person_birth;

-- Record for client and person data
client_rec client_cur%ROWTYPE;
person_rec person_cur%ROWTYPE;       

-- Record for client_match and person_match
client_match_rec client_cur%ROWTYPE;
person_match_rec person_cur%ROWTYPE;

-- For person data collection- create "table of records" (index-by table type collection)
TYPE person_t IS TABLE OF person_rec%ROWTYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
person_tab person_t;

-- For best client and person matches collections- create "table of records" (index-by table type collection) 
TYPE client_best_matches_t IS TABLE OF client_match_rec%ROWTYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
client_matches_tab client_best_matches_t;

TYPE person_best_matches_t IS TABLE OF person_match_rec%ROWTYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
person_matches_tab person_best_matches_t;


-- Variables
v_match_score number DEFAULT 0
v_temp_score number DEFAULT 0
v_match_threshold number DEFAULT 0 

BEGIN

-- Populate the person collection by processing the person cursor rows into the person records
OPEN person_cur;
LOOP
    FETCH person_cur INTO person_rec;
    EXIT WHEN person_cur%NOTFOUND;
    person_tab (person_cur%ROWCOUNT) := person_rec;
    END LOOP;

-- Process the client cursor rows into the client records 
OPEN client_cur;
LOOP
    FETCH client_cur INTO client_rec;
    EXIT WHEN client_cur%NOTFOUND;

/*
Inner loop compares one record in client to each record in person collection
Save match score in v_temp_score
Compare v_temp_score to v_match_score to see if this is the best match yet
If so, save records in best_match_client and best_match_person and save match score in v_match_score
*/
    IF person_tab IS NOT NULL
    THEN
    i := person_tab.FIRST;
    WHILE (i IS NOT NULL)
    LOOP
        (case when client_cur.nbr_client_ssn = person_tab.--HOW TO REFERENCE PERSON_TAB.SSN?
        then )

        i:= person_tab.NEXT (i);
        END LOOP;
    END IF;

 /*
If a match exists, add it to the collection for match results
Initialize the records and variables
*/

-- End outer loop

END LOOP;

END;
```

Comment: In order to reference `PERSON_TAB.SSN`, you need to update the `person_cur` cursor to expose it.  You have match_score/temp_score/etc but you don't use them.  My initial impression is that you don't need all the TYPEs you've defined...

Comment: I'm not sure what this means - " you need to update the person_cur cursor to expose it." I have defined match_score/temp_score etc. because I think I will need them to perform the comparisons (my goals are explained in the comments section before the inner loop), but again this was the beginnings of my code, and they are just placeholders for now. If there is a way I can do this without defining extra records, I will try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked:

> person_tab.--HOW TO REFERENCE PERSON_TAB.SSN?

Like this:

```
person_tab(i).ssn
```

Comment: Thanks, this directly answered my question. I assume this means that I do not have to specify the record, as the table(loop_index) will point to the correct "row."

Comment: That's right - person_tab(i) IS a record of type person_rec%ROWTYPE.

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot. Combined with the best practice suggestion from David above, I think I should be able to figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

The best practice here would be to use a single SQL statement if it is practicable to do so. Never do in PL/SQL what you can do in SQL.

In any case, avoid explicit cursors if you can do so and use the implicit syntax instead:

```
For x in (select table_name from user_tables)
Loop
   other_variable = x.table_name;
   etc. .....
End Loop;
```

Comment: If I use the above to define the implicit cursor, do I still need to define a record? Or do I just use the table(loop_index)? When do you define records vs. tables if you can reference a table's "record" using table(loop_index)?

Comment: With this implicit cursor syntax you are going to just loop through each row in the record. I'd suggest having a browse of the docs to get more info on attributes, but you do not have to create a record to select into.